# Why is querySelector dynamic value returning null?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a SPA using just vanilla JS, i want to select the element and then add an active class to it like so: `(document.getElementById(event.target.text).classList.add("active")`

can someone explain why the code below inst working?

`(document.getElementById(event.target.text)` returns null but the event.target.text is Home

`(document.getElementById(Home)` returns the actual element i need

Comment: Please check the data type of the event.target.text

Comment: It is a string.

need at least 15 characters...

Comment: Can't you use event.target.id for the same?

Comment: Ok Nuno Carro. It happens . Good you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the element id you can just u use event.target.id (assuming it has an id)

Comment: It does thank you for tip.

Figured it out, noob mistake, if i could i would delete the post but i am unable to..

Answer (score 0):

Try using

(document.getElementById(event.target.innerText) maybe.

Or jQuery $(event.target).text()

Comment: Still returning null, unfortunately